# MDX Query with Date Range Filter

Tags: date, mdx

I am new to the MDX queries. I am writing a MDX query to select a Measure value across months and I am putting date Range as filter here just to restrict no of Months returned. For eg I want Sales Revenue for each month in Date Range of 01-Jan-2014 to 30-Jun-2014. Ideally, it should give me sales value for six months i.e Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May and June. However when i write below query, I get error. PFB the below enter code here`ow query.

```
Select NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Target Plan Value]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY {[Realization Date].[Hierarchy].[Month Year].Members} ON ROWS
From [Cube_BCG_OLAP] 
( { [Realization Date].[Hierarchy].[Date].&[20140101] : 
[Realization Date].[Hierarchy].[Date].&[20141231] })
```

The error I get is The `Hierarchy` hierarchy already appears in the `Axis1` axis. Here Date and Month Year belong to same dimension table named as `Realization Date`. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You were missing the `WHERE` clause but I guess that was a typo. As your error message tells, you can't have members of the same hierarchy on two or more axes. In situations like this, you can use something like below which in MDX terminology is called `Subselect`.

```
Select NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Target Plan Value]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY {[Realization Date].[Hierarchy].[Month Year].Members} ON ROWS
From (
        SELECT 
        [Realization Date].[Hierarchy].[Date].&[20140101] : 
        [Realization Date].[Hierarchy].[Date].&[20141231] ON COLUMNS
        FROM [Cube_BCG_OLAP]
    )
```

Comment: Yep, do a rock-paper-scissor.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti could rock-paper-scissor but I reckon my approach is more standard - finding members from different hierarchies withing the same dimension is done with `EXISTS`. If I wanted the states of the USA I would use `EXISTS`.

Comment: Actually I found that "exists" works only with levels within hierarchy. For two unrelated dimensions, the "exists" don't work unless the third parameter, the measure group name is explicitly provided. So a bit hesitant to use that in such scenarios. Subselects however work all the time when it comes to filtering. But yes, your point taken.

Answer (score 3):

I like the exists function in this situation:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Target Plan Value]} 
  ON COLUMNS,
  NON EMPTY 
    EXISTS(
      [Realization Date].[Hierarchy].[Month Year].Members
      , {
         [Realization Date].[Hierarchy].[Date].&[20140101] : 
         [Realization Date].[Hierarchy].[Date].&[20141231]
        }
    ) 
  ON ROWS
FROM [Cube_BCG_OLAP]
```

Comment: @VikasBansal feel free to mark it as the answer if it answered your question: you also gain ponts for closing of questions by marking an answer as the correct answer.

Comment: was looking for the 

`
{
         [Realization Date].[Hierarchy].[Date].&[20140101] : 
         [Realization Date].[Hierarchy].[Date].&[20141231]
        }
`

Bit. Thanks

Comment: @SupunDeSilva feel free to mark it as the answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
[Measures].[Target Plan Value]} On Columns
{
[Realization Date].[Hierarchy].[Date].&[20140101].Parent : 
[Realization Date].[Hierarchy].[Date].&[20140631].Parent
} 
On Rows
From [Cube_BCG_OLAP]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create this same dimension only for filter in the cube, for example, dimension_filter -> hierarchy_filter -> level_filter