# How do I pull data from a date range of the 30th September 2019 to today in using MDX for PowerBI reports?

Tags: powerbi, mdx, powerbi-desktop

I need to pull a set of data from our SSAS cubes, between the start of a working year (30th September 2019) to the current date using MDX. This is for a PowerBI report. I've googled it but i'm not getting any results of use.

Any suggestions would be largely appreciated.

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY   { [Measures].[Fct Response Count] } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY   {   (   [Store].[ParentChain].[ParentChain].ALLMEMBERS 
                * [Store].[Chain].[Chain].ALLMEMBERS 
                * [Store].[StoreNum].[StoreNum].ALLMEMBERS 
                * [Store].[Store].[Store].ALLMEMBERS 
                * [Store].[PostCode].[PostCode].ALLMEMBERS 
                * [Dim User].[User Name].[User Name].ALLMEMBERS 
                * [Date].[Date].[Date].ALLMEMBERS 
                * [Dim Callfile].[Period Name].[Period Name].ALLMEMBERS 
                * [Dim Callfilevisit].[Callfile Visit Id].[Callfile Visit Id].ALLMEMBERS 
                * [SKU].[Brand].[Brand].ALLMEMBERS 
                * [SKU].[SKU].[SKU].ALLMEMBERS 
                * [Dim Survey Item].[Parent Question].[Parent Question].ALLMEMBERS 
                * [Dim Survey Item].[Question].[Question].ALLMEMBERS 
                * [Dim Subject].[Subject].[Subject].ALLMEMBERS 
                * [Dim Survey Item Response].[Response Text].[Response Text].ALLMEMBERS 
                ) 
            } 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, 
MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
FROM    (   SELECT 
                    (   { [Dim Survey Item].[Question].&[Display] } ) ON COLUMNS 
                    FROM ( SELECT ( { [Date].[Year].&[2020] } ) ON COLUMNS 
                    FROM [ClientSurvey])
        ) WHERE 
            ( [Date].[Year].&[2020] ) 
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, 
BACK_COLOR,
FORE_COLOR,
FORMATTED_VALUE,
FORMAT_STRING,
FONT_NAME,
FONT_SIZE,
FONT_FLAGS
```

Comment: Pull from where? In any case, Power BI uses M, not MDX. MDX is useful only when querying SSAS

Comment: why do you need to use MDX? PowerBI is using DAX and M natively

Comment: In any case, in Power BI you can simply design the report and inspect the generated M query

Comment: MDX is used to pull the data from the SSAS Cubes i believe.

Comment: Can you show the example MDX query? You can use a Where to define the range https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28086454/mdx-query-with-date-range-filter, there is a sort of getdate in mdx https://devmau5.wordpress.com/2010/03/25/the-getdate-of-mdx/

Comment: @Jonee I have attached the code in the main post